# how to avoid the compiler error for enumerable: false properties

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to learn TS and I came to a weird case scenario.

I have an object with a property set as non-enumerable:

```
let person = {
  name: 'Harry'
}

Object.defineProperty(person,'salary',{enumerable: false, value : 15});

console.log(person.salary); // 15
```

This works at runtime, however, the compiler is going to error:

> Property 'salary' does not exist on type '{ name: string; }'

which is expected.

I could bypass this setting the type of person as any, but it doesn't feel like a clean solution.

Is there another way to do it? The non-null assertion operator doesn't work for this.

I'd appreciate if anyone can share some knowledge about this.

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for. You've added a property, setting its enumerability to false. You get an error about its existence from the TypeScript compiler, which you are expecting. But you want to know how to not have this expected error? I mean `// @ts-ignore` will make the compiler ignore that and all TypeScript errors on the following line...

Comment: i am unable to reproduce your error, code you posted works fine

Comment: @Nonik This is *TypeScript*.

Comment: I was just curious about if it was a way to do it without using any or @ts-ignore but thanks for the input.

Comment: You could (ab)use `asserts` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mx3vbN). Is this similar to what you want?

Comment: @caTS i know...

Comment: @caTS That's a lovely workaround. Way complex for me but I like the idea of having a way of monkey-patch it :)
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think an assertion function wrapper for `Object.defineProperty()` is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could change the type annotation for `person`, maybe like:

```
let person: { name: string; salary?: number } = {
  name: 'Harry'
};
```

or even:

```
let person = {
  name: 'Harry'
} as { name: string; salary: number };
```

The safest method is probably (ab)using [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) in version 3.7:

```
function defineProperty<
    O,
    Property extends PropertyKey,
    Value
>(o: O, key: Property, attributes: PropertyDescriptor & ThisType<any> & { value: Value }): asserts o is O & Record<Property, Value> {
    Object.defineProperty(o, key, attributes);
}
```

It's essentially a wrapper function for `Object.defineProperty` that tells TypeScript, if this function doesn't throw an error, then the type of the given value `o` is `O & Record<Property, Value>`.

So when you use it, you get a type like this:

```
defineProperty(person,'salary',{enumerable: false, value : 15});

person
// ^? { name: string; } & Record<"salary", number>
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mx3vbN)

---

And if you *really* want to, you can also make the resulting type cleaner by changing the assertion to this:

```
asserts o is (O & Record<Property, Value> extends infer T extends O ? { [K in keyof T]: T[K] } : O)
```

As you can see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEwKbBmVAFATnAB1VygE8AeAWAChE7EB5AGhvsT0OLMVQA8pUYZAGd2+IiVIBpVKRa16ANQCGAGxCoaAPgAUcAFyMmiANazDHCWWPKoUXDABGIAcIviupACKphEBwRQcLiIAGSIACoAFjDCEaRE5MpgpFphiADeiABuahqGKuqoiAC+AJSGysLCXKJwiLGIOgzpAEqoEMHI5JaexoUaaXwCQqKYwMSRPPyCIoyIAPyZiADaUg1IZqRwwJEAuoYRa3uliIYMZZms9AyOAFYdUAB0aBhYvZJ6xls2dg7OrjKAG4aCUaDRVKgoIgJMIEIgALxXBRgZQAW1QhgA5AAJZS4XCkLGgkHUGi3B7QF7oTA4DyfWEIJhY4RqfFEpgZQQgDG4ZSOSGGYBqGrGXJFM6IACMAFZyqSaJ0wHDIU9VHAAOY6RlgJ6s1Ts4Hg6ivWkfMja4hwsDM-XsrGc7m8-mCxDC1SinJ5YqGWXy41KlWoNWay24a16tmEso0IA) when hovering over `person`, the type is now `{ name: string; salary: number; }` instead of an ugly intersection.